# Short URL with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So, I would like to make clear url/short url in web browser. I have read lots of htaccess tutorial... modrewrite etc. First, I tried in localhost (Xampp)  but Doesn't work...

Here is a link which I want to change :

```
localhost/proj/index.php?menulinks=contents/products
```

I would like to change the link like here :  `index/contents/products` or any kind of solution
And this is the htaccess :

```
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ index.php?menulinks=$1 [L]
```

It doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following to the htaccess should achieve what you are wanting.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /proj/index\.php\?menulinks=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /index/%2\? [R,L]

RewriteRule ^index/(.*)$ /proj/index.php?menulinks=$1 [L]
```

Will convert `proj/index.php?menulinks=contents/products` into `index/contents/products`

Comment: Oh,I think that it is better way but unfortunately I get 404 fail and now the url is the following:

localhost/index/contents/termekek

What is the problem ?

The solution is very close

Comment: I have added an extra line. That should work for you.